# How to get colDate row for every colA where max(denseRank) - 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve following:

```
colA     colDate     DenseRank
-------------------------------
a         2015-06-10     1
a         2015-06-09     2
b         2015-06-10     1
b         2015-06-09     2
b         2015-06-08     3
```

And i want to get this result

```
a   2015-06-10   1
b   2015-06-09   2
```

Is it possible to get this with query or i can get this only through t-sql? Can i get example of solution?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: It is sql server 2012. But it would be useful if i can do that by 2008. Can you give me idea what i am need to do to solve this?

Comment: I'm thinking a recursive cte with a group by on colA. Can't really provide code right now.

Comment: What is the logic for choosing the two rows?  It is not obvious to me.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I thought the same thing until I re-read the title :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? (Should work with SQL Server 2005+)

```
select colA, colDate, DenseRank
from (
   select colA, colDate, DenseRank, row_number() over (partition by colA order by DenseRank desc) rn
   from YourTable
) x
where x.rn = 2
```

**EDIT:** Changed to use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.

Also, you didn't specify, but I am assuming that for a given value of `colA`, you can't have any duplicate `DenseRank` values.